# How to sort ranking list with correct names output in C?

Tags: c, arrays, list, sorting

I'm trying to make a simple ranking list of a person Id and its name. The list is sorted by Id, in ascending order.

The inputs I enter is:

```
Enter: Id Name (5 time)
9 Ace
5 Bob
6 Cindy
7 Dean
2 Erik
```

The output I expect to get is

```
Sorted id is...
2        Erik
5        Bob
6        Cindy
7        Dean
9        Ace
```

The current result I get is

```
Sorted id is...
2        ABCDErik
5        BCDErik
6        CDErik
7        DErik
9        Erik
```

Below is the code I'm currently using. It's a Bubble Sort function:

```
int sorting(int n, int *array)
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            {
                temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j + 1];
                array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Main program:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j, temp;
    int num = 5;
    int *id = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);

    printf("Enter: Id Name (5 time) \n");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %s", &id[i], &name[i]);
    }

    sorting(num, id);

    printf("Sorted id is...\n");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t %s \n", id[i], &name[i]);
    }

    free(id);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make the correct names "chained" with its id?

Answer (score 1):

You have got your data stored in a wrong way. When you allocate memory with the intent to store strings inside, you have to properly calculate the memory size based on the string length.

Also having a `char *` is a pointer to one string, the array of strings should become `char * []`.

```
#define STRINGCOUNT 20
#define STRINGLEN 100

int maxlen= ... calculated somehow
int stringcnt= ... calculated somehow

char *stringarray[STRINGCOUNT];
for (i=0; i<STRINGCOUNT; i++)
   stringarray[i] = malloc(maxlen);
```

Another approach is to statically allocate the data:

```
char stringarray[STRINGCOUNT][STRINGLEN]
```

A third approach is to allocate everything dynamically. Note that with array of string pointers and dynamic allocation each string may be allocated of different length.

```
char **stringarray=calloc(stringcnt,sizeof(char *));
for (i=0; i<stringcnt; i++)
   stringarray[i] = malloc(maxlen);
// or
   stringarray[i] = strdup(somestring);
```

Also you have to keep in mind that is C strings are teminated with 0 character, so for storing Bob you will need at least 4 bytes.

What you currently do is to allocate 10 bytes buffer and them put there all the strings starting from different position.

About chaining data, the concept in the `C` language is called `struct`. In your case the definition will be

```
struct {
   int rank;
   char *name;
} items;
```

Structs can also be statically or dynamically allocated but you have to know that the name element is a pointer to a string and if not explicitly initialized it will not point to allocated memory and cannot be used.

Comment: is stringcount and MAXLEN are fixed number or they varried?

Comment: for malloc you can use variable buffer size

the other two should be fixed size, although gcc allows for dynamically allocating arrays on the stack, as you did in your code.

Comment: It's strange, the names are showing correctly now, but they are not sorted.

Comment: @LordRixuel: the names are not sorted because you never sort them. You need to pass both the numbers and the names to the sort function and you need to swap rows in both arrays to keep everything properly organized.  There are other ways to do it too. One is to use an array of structures, each of which holds an ID and a name.  Another is to create an array `ordering` with `ordering[n] = n` for each row 0..N-1 initially.  You then swap rows in this array, comparing `id[ordering[x]]` with `id[ordering[y]]`.  Then you can print the data in order using the sorted (permuted) `ordering` array.

Answer (score 1):

Of connecting two arrays it is index.
So to sort by passing the index and comparison sequences.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sorting(int n, int *array, int *indexs){
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < n -1 ; ++i){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j){
            if (array[indexs[i]] > array[indexs[j]]){
                temp = indexs[i];
                indexs[i] = indexs[j];
                indexs[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int i, j, temp;
    int num = 5;
    int *id = (int *) malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    int *indexs = malloc(num * sizeof(int));
    char **name = malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0 ; i < num ; ++i){
        name[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
        indexs[i] = i;
    }

    printf("Enter: Id Name (5 time) \n");
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
        scanf("%d %9s", &id[i], name[i]);

    sorting(num, id, indexs);

    printf("Sorted id is...\n");

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){
        printf("%d \t %s \n", id[indexs[i]], name[indexs[i]]);
        free(name[indexs[i]]);
    }
    free(id);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to **chain the names with their ids** is to use a structure and allocate an array of that structure. You can modify your program like this:

```
typedef struct name_id_pair {
  int id;
  char name[10];
} name_id_pair_t;



int sorting(int n, name_id_pair_t *array)
{
 int i, j;
name_id_pair_t temp;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); j++)
    {
        if (array[j].id > array[j + 1].id)
        {
            temp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
}

int main()
{
int i, j;
int num = 5;
name_id_pair_t *arr = (name_id_pair_t *) malloc(sizeof(name_id_pair_t) * 5);

printf("Enter: Id Name (5 time) \n");
for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    scanf("%d %s", &arr[i].id, &arr[i].name);
}

sorting(num, arr);

printf("Sorted id is...\n");

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    printf("%d \t %s \n", arr[i].id, arr[i].name);
}

free(arr);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never allocate memory for more than one name.

```
    char *name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
```

This allocates ten characters, plenty of room for one short name and that's it.